# Как преобразовать "\\n", "\\t" в "\n", "\t"

Tags: c#, строки

Я беру из текстового файла содержимое вида:

*Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nLine 4\nLine 5*

Необходимо преобразовать все управляющие символы в строке вроде *\n*, *\t* в перевод строки и табуляцию соответственно, так чтобы при выводе этой строки на экран выводилось
не так:

*Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nLine 4\nLine 5*

А так:

*Line 1*
*Line 2*
*Line 3*
*Line 4*
*Line 5*

Возможно реализовать это, при этом не прибегая к банальной замене "\n" на "\n", "\t" на "\t"?

Comment: Уточните, чем вас не устраивает *"банальная замена"*?

Comment: string.Replace(@"\n", "\n") вполне работает. Чем Вас не устраивает замена?

Comment: Устраивает и замена. Но если необходимая функция уже присутствует, то зачем её писать заново? Если её нет, то сделаю именно замену

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого есть специальные методы в BCL, например, [`Regex.Unescape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var s = @"Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3\nLine 4\nLine 5";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Unescape(s));
```